# Subsets Of A Set Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, products

I was asked the following question:

> Let $A={1,2,3}$ and $B={4,5}$. How many subsets does the set $A\times B$ contain of size at most $4$?

My understanding of the outer product $A\times B$ is that it produces a set of ordered pairs containing every combination of the elements of $A$ and $B$. In this case, it would be a set of six ordered pairs, no subsets. Am I totally misunderstanding what is meant by $A\times B$ in this context?

Comment: You are correct that $A\times B$ is a set of $6$ ordered pairs.  However you are incorrect in saying 'no subsets'.  It has subsets just as any set with six elements has.

Comment: Ah ok. I misunderstood the question then. I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If a set has $n$ elements then it has exactly $\binom{n}{k}$ subsets of size $k$.